# how to show the correct result of the quiz

Tags: php

I m trying to make a quiz.It's working but not giving the right result. On a correct answer for example answer 1 variable rans should be incremented by one but it is incrementing after submitting the 2nd question, that's why the value of the 10th current answer is not including in the total correct answer.

```
            <?php
      require_once("global.inc.php");?>
     <form name="test" method="post" action="test.php"> 
     <?php 
    $qid=(!isset($_POST['q_id'])) ? 0 : $_POST['q_id'];
    $rans=(!isset($_POST["rans"])) ? 0 : $_POST["rans"]; 
    $totalquestion=(!isset($_POST["totalquestion"])) ? 
            0 : $_POST["totalquestion"];  
    echo $rans;  

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
     {
     echo "<table align='center' style='border:1px solid silver' width='80%' 
    bgcolor='green'>"; 
     echo "<tr><td>Total Question Attempt</td><td>",$totalquestion,"</td><tr>"; 
     echo "<tr><td>Correct Answer</td><td>",$rans,"</td></tr>"; 
     echo "<tr><td>Wrong Answer</td><td>",$totalquestion-$rans,"</td></tr>"; 
     echo "<tr><td>Correct Answer Percentage</td> <td>",$rans/$totalquestion*100,"%</td></tr>"; 
     echo "<tr><td>Wrong Answer Percenntage</td><td>",($totalquestion-$rans)/$totalquestion*100,"%</td></tr>"; 
     echo "</table><br><br>"; 
     $query="select * from questions,answers 
             where questions.q_id=answers.q_id";

     echo "<table cellpadding='5px' align='center' style='border:1px 
    solid silver'>"; 
     echo "<tr><th colspan='4' id='heading'>Online Quiz Test 
    Question</td></tr>"; 
     $result=mysql_query($query); 
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
     echo "<tr><td>",$row['q_id'],"</td><td colspan='2'>",$row['question'],"</td></tr><tr><td></td>"; 
     echo "<td colspan='2'>A. ",$row['opt1'],"</td>"; 
     echo "<td colspan='2'>B. ",$row['opt2'],"</td></tr>"; 
     echo "<tr><td></td><td colspan='2'>C. ",$row['opt3'],"</td>"; 
     echo "<td colspan='1'>D. ",$row['opt4'],"</td></tr>"; 
     echo "<tr><td colspan='4' align='right' 
    style='color:orange'>Correct option is ",strtoupper($row['correct_ans']),"</td></tr>"; 
     echo "<tr><td colspan='4' align='right' 
    style='color:orange'><hr></td></tr>"; 

     } 
     echo "</table>"; 
     echo "<p align='right'><a href='#' onclick='window.print()'>Print</a></p>"; 
     echo "<div style='visibility:hidden;display:none'>"; 

     } 

     ?>
       <form name="test" method="post" action="test.php"> 
     <?php
       if(!isset($a))
        {   
            $a=0;

        //unset($_SESSION['score']);
        }


        if(isset($_POST['next'])) {
            $a=$_POST['a'];
            $totalquestion=$_POST['totalquestion'];  
            if(isset($_POST['rans']))
            $rans=$_POST['rans'];       

            }

        $sql1="SELECT * FROM questions,answers 
                   where questions.q_id=answers.q_id limit 1 offset $a";
        $result=mysql_query($sql1);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "<form method='post' action=''>";


        if($result) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {

        $qid = $row["q_id"];

        $questions = $row["question"];

        $opt1 = $row["opt1"];

        $opt2 = $row["opt2"];

        $opt3 = $row["opt3"];

        $opt4 = $row["opt4"];

        $correct = $row["correct_ans"];
        echo $rans;
    ?>


         <p >Q.<?php echo $qid ?> <?php echo $questions;?></p>
 <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $opt1;?>" name="choice"/><?php echo $opt1;?>    <br/>
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $opt2;?>" name="choice"/><?php echo $opt2;?><br/>
 <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $opt3;?>" name="choice"/><?php echo $opt3;?><br/>
 <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $opt4;?>" name="choice"/><?php echo $opt4;?><br/>
 <input type="hidden" value="$answer" name="rightanswer[$qid]"/>


     <?php   

         $b=$a+1;   


        $sql2="SELECT * FROM questions where q_id=$qid-1 ";
        $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $ans=$row2['correct_ans'];

        }    


        if(isset($_POST['choice'])) {
        if($ans==$_POST['choice']){
        //echo "<input type='hidden' name='rans' value='".($rans+1). "'>"; 
        $rans=$rans+1; 
        } 
        else {
        //echo "<input type='hidden' name='rans' value='" . $rans . "'>"; 
         $rans=$rans;
        }
        }

        //$query="select correct_ans from questions where q_id='$qid'"; 
         //$result=mysql_query($query); 
        //while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //echo $row['correct_ans']; 

    echo "<input type='hidden' value='$b' name='a'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='count' name='count'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name=qid value='$qid'>";

   echo "<input type='hidden' name='totalquestion' value='".$totalquestion+1)."'>";

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='rans' value='" . $rans . "'>"; 

        echo "<input type='submit' name='next' value='next'> ";

        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'><br><br>";

     echo "</form>";
    }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: $Mysql_* is deprecated due to security concerns. User mysqli or pdo in the future also, USE PREPARED STATEMENTS!

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `$rans=$rans;`

Comment: $rans=$rans is to assign the previous value of rans(right answer) on wrong answer.@Snowburnt

Comment: except all it does is assign $rans to itself.  It's a completely useless piece of code.

Comment: you also realize that if someone does a view code they can see the right answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your code is a bit of a mess.

You have random tautologies (like the `$rans=$rans;` which does absolutely nothing.  If the answerer clicks "next" you're assigning `$totalquestion` twice. Definitely take a good, hard look and refactor this page.

But the answer to your question is probably because you're checking to see if they entered in the right answer at the bottom of the code -- after you've presented the results or the next question.

You've utilized the scripting capabilities of PHP without touching on any functions so it will evaluate top to bottom.

I'd move everything around:  Move the handler for "next" to the top, underneath your default variable assignments, then put the check for right answer underneath that, then do the presentation of the next question, then the "submit"handler.

I'd break up the different units into functions for readability and reusability, also.  For example, make a function to print out the specified question, make another one to validate the user entered in the right answer.

Comment: Thanks Snowburnt, I rearranged my code segments as per your suggestion and now it's working properly @Snowburnt